# how to convert List to Map in java 8, .map function is in the chain

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class

```
class Passenger {
   String type;
   String firstName;
   String lastName;

   //getter,setter
   public String getName() {
     return firstName + " " + lastName
 } 
}
```

now i want to convert List of passenger to Map, where key is "type" and value is List of "name"

i am try to achieve this as below,

```
passengerList.stream().map(w -> w.getName()).collect(groupBy( getType() ));
```

but as after .map function Passenger has been mapped to firstName,type is not available any more, donot know how to do this.

Answer (score 7):

You have to `groupingBy` first and then use `mapping` to get a `List` of the names for each type :

```
Map<String,List<String>> namesByType = 
    passengerList.stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Passenger::getType,
                                                Collectors.mapping(Passenger::getName,
                                                                   Collectors.toList())));
```